# Allign block content next to title - CSS

Tags: theming, bootstrap-theme

My goal is to display a button group to the right of the page title. Currently it resides in *region-content*, which wastes space.[image: input group]
I tried adding my own class to the *div* that contains *btn-group* class and use *margin-top* to move it up, but as soon as I save content, I get system help message that overlaps with the button group.

I also tried to add the block to other regions and get same thing if, say, I use breadcrumbs.

What's the best way or what are the classes I should use to position my block with button group to the right of the page title in *main-container* instead of *region-content*?

Comment: This is hard to answer without knowing more about your HTML structure/theme/page template, but one sure-fire way to do this is with absolute positioning, though that's probably not ideal. You could also try to style your system help messages to not overlap the buttons. But if adding a block into the same region the page title is in won't work, you may need to modify your page template or use JavaScript.

Comment: I'm using [Bootstrap 3](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) out of the box theme settings. The only thing I did is used the sub theme, which have not been modified yet.

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't help me that much. What version of Drupal are you using? Also, would it be possible for you to provide a link to this page or to at least copy the essential section of the page (as shown in the screenshot) over to Code Pen or jsfiddle or a similar site?

Comment: Sure, here's the link to demo I set up a while ago: http://admincenter.semargl.ca/contracts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after looking at your demo, there's a couple things you can do.

The easiest method is to simply float `#block-block-16` right, float `.page-header` left, set `#block-system-main` to `clear: both`, and be done with it.

But that's not great because we are kinda circumventing `div.region.region-content` by doing that. It'd be better if the header and the buttons actually shared a common parent. That seems to be what you truly want to do here. We can accomplish that with some JavaScript. That will also help with the minor problem the first solution introduces of having your gray underline not stretch across the page.

```
$(function() {

  $('#block-block-16').insertAfter($('h1.page-header'));
  $('#block-block-16, h1.page-header').wrapAll('<div id="top-container" class="clearfix"></div>');

});
```

From here, again we'll just float the buttons right and the page header left as before.

We can also take care of some details and clearfix the new div (included in the JS) and perhaps change our bottom border from being set on the h1 to being set on our new div, so that it stretches across the page, below the header and buttons.

You may also choose to remove the 9px padding-bottom on the h1 and instead change that to a 9px padding-top on `div.region.region-content`.

Hope that helps!